How to remove extra whitespace when line breaks
I have a <h4> element and css like this


.hero-title {
  background: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 473px;
}
<h4 class="hero-title">
  <span>Vessel / tank destruction facility</span>
</h4>



Here is the outcome:

I want to remove the extra spacing on the right side, so that the black background ends at "Vessel / tank", in other words, when line break happens, it should align with the widest word and not take up the entire 473px width.

This might not be solution for you but I generally adjust width like wise that no white-space remains which  gets job done unless you have dynamic data. m-sarabi doing same thing but with js.

I made you a snippet. You need to wrap it is some constraining div to show the issue

I couldn't find any CSS method to do this. I only found this solution using JavaScript.
Basically, we calculate the bounding box of the text and then determine the width of the parent based on that. (Just make sure that box-sizing is set to border-box.):


function adjustContainerWidth(element) {
  const textSpan = element.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
  const boundingRect = textSpan.getBoundingClientRect();
  const horizontalPadding = parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).paddingLeft) + parseInt(getComputedStyle(element).paddingRight);
  element.style.width = (boundingRect.width + horizontalPadding) + 'px';
}

const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hero-title'));
elements.forEach((element) => {
  adjustContainerWidth(element);
});
.hero-title {
    background: #000;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    max-width: 473px;
    box-sizing: border-box;  /* for correct width calculation */
    font-size: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
}
<h4 class="hero-title">
  <span>Vessel / tank destruction facility</span>
</h4>




You can use this solution only with CSS.


.shrink-box {
  max-width: 470px;  
  width: fit-content; 
  padding: 10px;      
  border: 1px solid #000;
  word-wrap: break-word; 
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Footer at Bottom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="shrink-box">
  <span>Vessel / tank<br>destruction<br> facility</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>




Please explain how this code solves the issues. Code-only answers are not good answers
